# Transforming from BOX2DF to BOX

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-etl

I am using some legacy code which requires my data in PostgreSQL box type e.g. this format `(37357,50073),(34242,357)`.

However, I am using PostGIS with box2df i.e. I get: `BOX2DF(588893 4515997, 600342 4517442.5)`. Is there a PostGIS/PostgreSQL function which can transform my data from the BOX2DF format to the BOX format?

I cannot simply do a type cast:

> ERROR:  cannot cast type box2df to box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the output (convert-to-text) function is defined for the `BOX2DF` internal type, so you should be able to convert it to text and then to `BOX2D` with string manipulation:

```
SELECT replace(mybox2df::text, '2DF', '')::box2d
```

To get the native PostgreSQL `box` type, I think you'd need to break out some regular expressions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION box2df_to_box (box2df) 
RETURNS BOX AS $$
DECLARE matches text[];
BEGIN
  SELECT array_agg(regexp_matches[1]) FROM (SELECT regexp_matches($1::text, '\d+[.]?\d*', 'g')) sq INTO matches;
  RETURN box(point(matches[2]::float, matches[3]::float), point(matches[4]::float, matches[5]::float));
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: Thanks. Then the transformed output is `BOX(588893 4515997,600342 4517442.5)` which is still not exactly like the original box type. Not sure if this is right.

Comment: My bad, I assumed you meant the PostGIS box type, not the PostgreSQL box type.

Comment: @audlift-bit Edited w/code to get native PostgreSQL box.